# Disable Google Map Movement on double tap in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, gesture, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am using the Google Maps SDK for my iOS App.

You can zoom in on the map using either of two gestures.

1. Double Tap
2. Double Tap -> Hold -> Drag Down

In the first way, the map zooms in, but the map shifts near to the position where I double tap.
While in the second method, the map zooms in staying at the current map centre.

I want to achieve the second type of behaviour(map staying on current centre rather than shifting) on the first gesture too. How do I go about it?

EDIT: Basically the behaviour should be same as the Official Google Map Double Tap.

Comment: Try this:                               googleMapView.settings.zoomGestures = NO;

Answer (score 5):

This is a config item in GMSUISettings class, so you can access it on your `GMSMapView` object's 'settings' property like below,

Obj-C:

```
mapView.settings.allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom = NO;
```

Swift 2.1:

```
mapView.settings.allowScrollGesturesDuringRotateOrZoom = false
```

I had to dig into their source code to find this config item, its not mentioned anywhere in the docs.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the default gestures on the map by setting properties of the GMSUISettings class, which is available as a property of the GMSMapView. The following gestures can be enabled and disabled programmatically. Note disabling the gesture will not limit programmatic access to the camera settings.

scrollGestures — controls whether scroll gestures are enabled or disabled. If enabled, users may swipe to pan the camera.

zoomGestures — controls whether zoom gestures are enabled or disabled. If enabled, users may double tap, two-finger tap, or pinch to zoom the camera. Note that double tapping may pan the camera to the specified point.

tiltGestures — controls whether tilt gestures are enabled or disabled. If enabled, users may use a two-finger vertical down or up swipe to tilt the camera.

rotateGestures — controls whether rotate gestures are enabled or disabled. If enabled, users may use a two-finger rotate gesture to rotate the camera.

In the below example, both pan and zoom gestures have been disabled.

```
(void)loadView {
  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:1.285
                                                          longitude:103.848
                                                               zoom:12];
  mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
  mapView_.settings.scrollGestures = NO;
  mapView_.settings.zoomGestures = NO;
  self.view = mapView_;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that is not the behaviour I was looking for. I don't want to disable the scroll and zoom functionality. I just want that the map does not shift the centre position while I double tap.

Comment: @ArnavPatra Check out my answer, certainly solves your problem.